# how to create a Photoshop Script dialog box for rotation on 360 on layer

Tags: photoshop

this script create a simple horizontal line from the center of my image on a new layer to the right at 0 degree. I would like to have a dialog box that appear asking me to how much degree I want to rotate that line from the center. A little like a watch.
Can you help me on that please? I really don't know how to do that. I have created that JSX file from Photoshop Script Listener, but when I try to create rotation, it seems that the listener does not work. I use Photoshop CC 2019
tks
Seby

```
// =======================================================
var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref1 = new ActionReference();
        var idmoveTool = stringIDToTypeID( "moveTool" );
        ref1.putClass( idmoveTool );
    desc5.putReference( idnull, ref1 );
    var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
    desc5.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
    var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
    desc5.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
executeAction( idslct, desc5, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();
        var idlineTool = stringIDToTypeID( "lineTool" );
        ref2.putClass( idlineTool );
    desc6.putReference( idnull, ref2 );
    var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
    desc6.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
    var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
    desc6.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
executeAction( idslct, desc6, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
    var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref3 = new ActionReference();
        var idcontentLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "contentLayer" );
        ref3.putClass( idcontentLayer );
    desc7.putReference( idnull, ref3 );
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
        var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idType = charIDToTypeID( "Type" );
            var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
            var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
                var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
                desc10.putDouble( idRd, 0.000000 );
                var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
                desc10.putDouble( idGrn, 0.000000 );
                var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
                desc10.putDouble( idBl, 0.000000 );
            var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
            desc9.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc10 );
        var idsolidColorLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "solidColorLayer" );
        desc8.putObject( idType, idsolidColorLayer, desc9 );
        var idShp = charIDToTypeID( "Shp " );
            var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();
            var idStrt = charIDToTypeID( "Strt" );
                var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
                var idRlt = charIDToTypeID( "#Rlt" );
                desc12.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idRlt, 126.000000 );
                var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
                var idRlt = charIDToTypeID( "#Rlt" );
                desc12.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idRlt, 126.000000 );
            var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
            desc11.putObject( idStrt, idPnt, desc12 );
            var idEnd = charIDToTypeID( "End " );
                var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
                var idRlt = charIDToTypeID( "#Rlt" );
                desc13.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idRlt, 247.920000 );
                var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
                var idRlt = charIDToTypeID( "#Rlt" );
                desc13.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idRlt, 126.000000 );
            var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
            desc11.putObject( idEnd, idPnt, desc13 );
            var idWdth = charIDToTypeID( "Wdth" );
            var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
            desc11.putUnitDouble( idWdth, idPxl, 6.000000 );
        var idLn = charIDToTypeID( "Ln  " );
        desc8.putObject( idShp, idLn, desc11 );
        var idstrokeStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyle" );
            var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();
            var idstrokeStyleVersion = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleVersion" );
            desc14.putInteger( idstrokeStyleVersion, 2 );
            var idstrokeEnabled = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeEnabled" );
            desc14.putBoolean( idstrokeEnabled, false );
            var idfillEnabled = stringIDToTypeID( "fillEnabled" );
            desc14.putBoolean( idfillEnabled, true );
            var idstrokeStyleLineWidth = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineWidth" );
            var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
            desc14.putUnitDouble( idstrokeStyleLineWidth, idPxl, 1.000000 );
            var idstrokeStyleLineDashOffset = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineDashOffset" );
            var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );
            desc14.putUnitDouble( idstrokeStyleLineDashOffset, idPnt, 0.000000 );
            var idstrokeStyleMiterLimit = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleMiterLimit" );
            desc14.putDouble( idstrokeStyleMiterLimit, 100.000000 );
            var idstrokeStyleLineCapType = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineCapType" );
            var idstrokeStyleLineCapType = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineCapType" );
            var idstrokeStyleButtCap = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleButtCap" );
            desc14.putEnumerated( idstrokeStyleLineCapType, idstrokeStyleLineCapType, idstrokeStyleButtCap );
            var idstrokeStyleLineJoinType = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineJoinType" );
            var idstrokeStyleLineJoinType = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineJoinType" );
            var idstrokeStyleMiterJoin = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleMiterJoin" );
            desc14.putEnumerated( idstrokeStyleLineJoinType, idstrokeStyleLineJoinType, idstrokeStyleMiterJoin );
            var idstrokeStyleLineAlignment = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineAlignment" );
            var idstrokeStyleLineAlignment = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineAlignment" );
            var idstrokeStyleAlignInside = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleAlignInside" );
            desc14.putEnumerated( idstrokeStyleLineAlignment, idstrokeStyleLineAlignment, idstrokeStyleAlignInside );
            var idstrokeStyleScaleLock = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleScaleLock" );
            desc14.putBoolean( idstrokeStyleScaleLock, false );
            var idstrokeStyleStrokeAdjust = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleStrokeAdjust" );
            desc14.putBoolean( idstrokeStyleStrokeAdjust, false );
            var idstrokeStyleLineDashSet = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleLineDashSet" );
                var list1 = new ActionList();
            desc14.putList( idstrokeStyleLineDashSet, list1 );
            var idstrokeStyleBlendMode = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleBlendMode" );
            var idBlnM = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );
            var idNrml = charIDToTypeID( "Nrml" );
            desc14.putEnumerated( idstrokeStyleBlendMode, idBlnM, idNrml );
            var idstrokeStyleOpacity = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleOpacity" );
            var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
            desc14.putUnitDouble( idstrokeStyleOpacity, idPrc, 100.000000 );
            var idstrokeStyleContent = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleContent" );
                var desc15 = new ActionDescriptor();
                var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
                    var desc16 = new ActionDescriptor();
                    var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
                    desc16.putDouble( idRd, 0.000000 );
                    var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
                    desc16.putDouble( idGrn, 0.000000 );
                    var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
                    desc16.putDouble( idBl, 0.000000 );
                var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
                desc15.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc16 );
            var idsolidColorLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "solidColorLayer" );
            desc14.putObject( idstrokeStyleContent, idsolidColorLayer, desc15 );
            var idstrokeStyleResolution = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleResolution" );
            desc14.putDouble( idstrokeStyleResolution, 300.000000 );
        var idstrokeStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyle" );
        desc8.putObject( idstrokeStyle, idstrokeStyle, desc14 );
    var idcontentLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "contentLayer" );
    desc7.putObject( idUsng, idcontentLayer, desc8 );
    var idLyrI = charIDToTypeID( "LyrI" );
    desc7.putInteger( idLyrI, 126 );
executeAction( idMk, desc7, DialogModes.NO );
```

Comment: Look for `Photoshop ScriptUI`

Comment: tks, but this is really what i'm asking for on how to do it please. tks

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn Photoshop Script UI. Though it is notoriously badly supported by Adobe. There are a few websites that tell you. Do a search for "ScriptUI for Dummies"; It's a good place to start.

Here's a simple slider that will rotate the layer to the value as required. You can also use the transform function taken from Scriptlistener.

Even if you don't know what code to use you can always ask and show an example in pseudo code.

```
// your code 
// do something

//
// dialog
var dlg = new Window("dialog"); 
   dlg.text = "Something"; 
   dlg.preferredSize.width = 360; 
   dlg.orientation = "column"; 
   dlg.alignChildren = ["center","top"]; 
   dlg.spacing = 10; 
   dlg.margins = 16; 

var slider1 = dlg.add("slider", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {name: "slider1"}); 
   slider1.minvalue = 0; 
   slider1.maxvalue = 360; 
   slider1.value = 0; 
   slider1.preferredSize.width = 300; 

var statictext1 = dlg.add("statictext", undefined, undefined, {name: "statictext1"}); 
   statictext1.text = slider1.value;
   statictext1.preferredSize.width = 80; 
   statictext1.justify = "center"; 


// add buttons
dlg.add ("button", undefined, "OK");
dlg.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");


// Define behavior for when the slider1 value changes
dlg.slider1.onChanging = function() 
{
    var valSlider1 = Math.round(dlg.slider1.value);
    // Update the label text with the current slider value.
    dlg.statictext1.text = valSlider1;
} 

// show the dlg;
dlg.center();

var myReturn = dlg.show();



if (myReturn)
{
   var myAngle = parseInt(dlg.statictext1.text);
   var msg = dlg.statictext1.text + " degrees rotation";
   alert(msg);
   transform (myAngle);
}


function transform (rot)
{
   if (rot == undefined) return;
   //transform
   // =======================================================
   var id769 = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
   var desc98 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var id770 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
   var ref59 = new ActionReference();
   var id771 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
   var id772 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
   var id773 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
   ref59.putEnumerated( id771, id772, id773 );
   desc98.putReference( id770, ref59 );
   var id774 = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
   var id775 = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
   var id776 = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
   desc98.putEnumerated( id774, id775, id776 );
   var id777 = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
   var desc99 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var id778 = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
   var id779 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
   desc99.putUnitDouble( id778, id779, 0); // dX
   var id780 = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
   var id781 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
   desc99.putUnitDouble( id780, id781, 0 ); // dY
   var id782 = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
   desc98.putObject( id777, id782, desc99 );
   var id783 = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
   var id784 = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
   desc98.putUnitDouble( id783, id784, rot );
   executeAction( id769, desc98, DialogModes.NO );
}
```